# postgresql create function dynamically insert value into different table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I want to create a function that can dynamically insert any data type value into any table and multiple columns. But my function can only insert one value to one column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.dynamic_insert(
                  tablename character varying,
                  columname character varying,
                  datatype character varying,
                  valuee text
                                              )
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE AS
$BODY$
begin

    Execute format('insert into %I ('||columname||') 
               values (cast($1 as '||datatype||'))',tablename,columname);

end;
$BODY$;
```

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your idea clearly. I guess that you want to write one function to insert into table with list of column and values you specify. 
If I guess correctly. I suggest some function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.dynamic_insert(
                  tablename character varying,
                  columname character varying[],
                  datatype character varying[],
                  valuee character varying[]
                                              )
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
       var_sql varchar;
       var_sql_column varchar := '';
       var_sql_values varchar := '';

begin

    var_sql_column := CONCAT('("',ARRAY_TO_STRING(columname, '","'),'")');

    FOR i IN 1..ARRAY_LENGTH(columname,1)
    LOOP
        var_sql_values := var_sql_values || quote_literal(valuee[i]) || '::' || datatype[i] || ',';
    END LOOP;

    var_sql_values := CONCAT('(',regexp_replace(var_sql_values, ',$', '', 'g'),')');

    var_sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', quote_ident(tablename), var_sql_column, ' VALUES ', var_sql_values);

    IF (var_sql IS NOT NULL) THEN
        EXECUTE(var_sql);
    END IF;

end;
$BODY$;
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE;
```

Hopefully it matches your require.

p/s: with my experience, just choose one solution between `Format`, and `String concatenation`, don't use both in one query, it makes me hard to view and find bug.

------------- Update for question below -----------------------------------

For the Loop please refer the document [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS)

Basically, it will run from 1 to n (with n is the number elements in array) and build a query.

One simple thing to view how it run is you can put some print out data into you function, such as `RAISE`. Please refer it document [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html)

Comment: Hi Kolesen, how does this part works?FOR i IN 1..ARRAY_LENGTH(columname,1)
    LOOP
        var_sql_values := var_sql_values || quote_literal(valuee[i]) || '::' || datatype[i] || ',';
    END LOOP;

Comment: Dear Rick Jiang, 
please check my answer above.